# the dunn test is not working with error about coersion

Tags: r

I am trying to get the dunn  test to work and I get an erro about coersion:

```
   dt = data.frame(c = 1:50 , group = rep(  c("a","b") ,each=25)  )

        dunn.test(dt$c   ~   dt$group )

Error in dunn.test(dt$c ~ dt$group) : 
  'pairlist' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(unlist(x)) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error - it's because dunn.test() wants a comma between the variables not a ~

So this works:

```
dt = data.frame(c = 1:50 , group = rep(  c("a","b") ,each=25)  )

dunn.test(dt$c , dt$group )
```